# Posting XML to WebAPI - parameter is aways null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post XML to an action method. The parameter is always null. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

The controller class:

```
namespace TestNetCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public Book AddBook([FromBody]Book b) <-- b is always null
        {
            return new Book
            {
                Id = b.Id,
                Title = b.Title
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
            .AddMvcOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                opts.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

In project.json I have added this:

```js
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.1"
```

The model class:

```
namespace TestNetCore.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Book
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The script that sends XML:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/book",
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            method: "POST",
            data: { b: "<Book xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestNetCore.Models\"><Id>1</Id><Title>Programming Book</Title></Book>" },
            success: function (book) {
                addBook(book);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        })
    });
});

function addBook(book) {
    $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + book.id + "</td><td>" + book.title + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using json?

Comment: @AndreiFilimon: I used json before and it worked as intended. The reason I wanted to use XML is beacuse I'm new to WebAPI and wanted to learn how to pass XML instead of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is the problem, you are sending an object with a property named b that contains a string (the xml content) and this doesn't match the action contract with expects and object Book and it's properties:

```
data: { b: "<Book xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestNetCore.Models\"><Id>1</Id><Title>Programming Book</Title></Book>" },
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I should have noted that simple error.